# NowJS Javascript Getting in running?

Tags: javascript, nowjs-sockets

I've had nowjs installed on the server http://nowjs.com/ and I want to try out a chat so

I've done this and uploaded it to the server... http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2535  ...

it now says I need run  this: $ node nowjschatserver.js ...

where do I run that by adding it to the html or js file?

I don't understand how to run that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to have shell access on the host to run this command. In cpanel, take a look here:  http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ShellAccess

Once you have access to the shell, then you need to `cd` to the directory where your `helloworld_server.js` file is and run that command.

Answer (score 1):

See : http://nowjs.com/doc/example

Comment: This is what I don't understand..."Run node helloworld_server.js in your terminal. " .. What Terminal? I have a linux host, whm and cpanel.

Comment: It refers to the Terminal on your local machine assuming you are on Unix/Mac

Comment: But I don't so what can I do to get this done on my host online?

Comment: Have you installed nodejs on your server?

Comment: Yes, the host support installed it for me.